# Caliper test using exec-maven-plugin is saying main method signature isn't valid

Tags: java, maven, benchmarking, exec-maven-plugin, caliper

I'm trying to get Caliper working with maven, I haven't successfully ran a caliper benchmark test as of yet.

Caliper version: 1.0-beta-1

My benchmark:

```
public class MyXercesSAXHandlerBenchmark extends Benchmark{

    @Param({"10", "100", "1000", "10000"}) private int length;


    public void timeNanoTime(int reps) {
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
            System.nanoTime();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CaliperMain.main(MyXercesSAXHandlerBenchmark.class, args);
    }
}
```

My maven pom.xml has:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>benchmarks</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>caliper</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>java</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                                <mainClass>my.path.to.benchmark.MyXercesSAXHandlerBenchmark</mainClass>
                                <arguments>


                                </arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I ran:

mvn clean install
mvn compile -P benchmarks -e -X

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. The specified mainClass doesn't contain a main method with appropriate signature.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: The specified mainClass doesn't contain a main method with appropriate signature.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:294)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.google.caliper.runner.CaliperMain.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1632)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:283)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: You've defined `<mainClass>com.google.caliper.runner.CaliperMain</mainClass>` in Maven but post the main method inside `MyXercesSAXHandlerBenchmark`?!

Comment: I changed the main class to my main class and now I get: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:`

Comment: can you update your post accordingly?

Comment: I have updated my question with the change in my pom.

Comment: and the exception? which class was maven not able to find? `MyXercesSAXHandlerBenchmark`? or Caliper?

Comment: `caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: path.to.my.MyXercesSAXHandlerBenchmark`   It seems it just can't find the class, why would it not be visible?

Comment: My benchmark code is inside of /src/test/java/...  could that be the reason it can't see it?  Does the compile phase include the test?

Comment: and `path.to.my....` is the fully qualified class name? (= the package name + class name (each separated by a `.`)). As you are compiling the code via maven, it should be able to find the .class files of your main class. Maybe the phase compile could be problematic? Try setting it to test. Moreover, [SO offers a few examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472376/how-do-i-execute-a-program-using-maven) on how it can be configured. From what I know `<classpathScope>test</classpathScope>` should take the classes generated from `src/test/java`

Comment: Ok looks like that was one issue, now it can't find a jar `ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't find required allocationinstrumenter agent jar`  I added the artifact `java-allocation-instrumenter` with test scope but still dont' work.

Answer (score 0):

The `maven-exec-plugin` doesn't work with `1.0-beta-1`.  You need to build caliper from a revision later than `6d05814727e8b119651247952dedf4ab321d890a` - `HEAD`, of course, works.

Comment: So I build and referenced the revision 6d058, but I still see the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't find required allocationinstrumenter agent jar`.

Comment: That happens when Caliper can't find https://code.google.com/p/java-allocation-instrumenter/ on the classpath.  It is a transitive dependency of Caliper, so you should have it automatically.  I'm not sure what's happening with your classpath management to have it go missing.  You can set it manually using the flag -Cinstrument.allocation.options.allocationAgentJar=/path/to/the.jar if you can't resolve the dependency management issues.