# How to reference a local repository in maven?

Tags: java, maven, caliper

I downloaded the source and built caliper like this:

```
mvn eclipse:configure-workspace eclipse:eclipse install
```

Now the /target folder has:

```
caliper-1.0-beta-SNAPSHOT-all.jar     generated-sources                     surefire
caliper-1.0-beta-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar generated-test-sources                surefire-reports
caliper-1.0-beta-SNAPSHOT.jar         maven-archiver                        test-classes
classes                               maven-status
```

Now in my spring mvc application's pom file, how do I reference this local repository that I just installed?

I was referencing caliper using a dependancy like this:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.caliper</groupId>
        <artifactId>caliper</artifactId>
        <version>${caliper-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But as per my last question I was advised to build from source to get an update that isn't published yet: [Caliper test using exec-maven-plugin is saying main method signature isn't valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070459/caliper-test-using-exec-maven-plugin-is-saying-main-method-signature-isnt-valid)

So I am not sure how to reference this caliper version that I built locally and installed using maven.

Comment: Can you use the -o option to use mvn in offline mode, to use local repositories?

Answer (score 1):

By invoking `mvn install`, you installed the project into your **local repository**. Maven will use the local artifacts, in case they are available. Please note, the */target* folder is **not** the local repository!

Have a look at

- `~/.m2/repository` on Linux/Mac
- Something like `C:\Documents and Settings\{your-username}\.m2\repository` on Windows.

You can have a look there, if the jar is available in the folder com/google/caliper/caliper/1.0-BETA-SNAPSHOT/

So if you correctly have build and installed the *caliper* artifact, you can reference it in your project and maven will resolve it from your local repository. If it is not available there, it will try to resolve it from [Maven central](http://search.maven.org/) or repositories you have configured.

Be sure to check that the version of caliper is **correctly referenced** in your project pom, if I understand you correctly, this would mean: *1.0-beta-SNAPSHOT*. It seems that you use a variable `${caliper-version}`, double check if this variable is defined correctly and references the correct version.

You might read the [introduction to repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) for more information.

Comment: great thanks, so it looks local before maven central it seems thanks.

Comment: Yes, for releases artifacts, it checks remote, if there is no local version. For SNAPSHOTs, it checks if there is a newer one available remote. If it's newer, it will be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If version is eg 1.0-SNAPSHOT then place the jar here

```
localrepo_folder
  com
     google
        caliper
           caliper  <-- artifact
               1.0-SNAPSHOT
                    caliper-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```