# How do I use maven, keep getting noClassDefFoundError

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, android-maven-plugin

New to maven trying to add a dependency

```
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.koushikdutta.ion</groupId>
   <artifactId>ion</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

And then I update the project and I see the necessary jar files generated in the maven dependencies folder

So then in my activity I want to use Ion so I call it like this

```
try {
        Ion.with(mContext, uri).asBitmap().setCallback(new FutureCallback<Bitmap>() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, Bitmap result) {

                try {
                    if (e != null) {
                        throw e;
                    }

                    setImage(v, result);

                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I make the necessary imports and there are no errors in the file but at runtime

```
    03-07 21:05:40.492: E/AndroidRuntime(778): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-2
03-07 21:05:40.492: E/AndroidRuntime(778): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion
```

What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: do maven clean once.. and check class is available on buildpath: by ctrl+shift+t type Ion..

Comment: Yeah it shows up but still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

How do you execute the program?  From maven?  From the command-line?  It sounds like the execution environment does not share the same classpath as the compile-time environment in you maven POM file.

Comment: I'm using eclipse, before I would just run it as an android program on my phone, am i supposed to be doing something different?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I can confirm that the dependency does contain the missing class:

- http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22com.koushikdutta.ion%22%20AND%20a%3A%22ion%22%20AND%20v%3A%221.2.4%22AND%20fc%3A%22com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion%22

This is no real surprise because you state that the code did compile. The problem is the classpath management at **runtime**.

### Option 1: Use Maven to launch the app

Run the code from within Maven using the [exec plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/). This will setup the programs classpath based on the dependencies you have declared in your POM:

- [How do I execute a program using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472376/how-do-i-execute-a-program-using-maven)

### Option 2: Create executable jar

A standalone jar that understands what it's dependencies  are (without a POM):

- [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)
- http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/08/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-in-maven/

For more detail on the internals of a jar I recommend reading the [jar spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Main_Attributes), specifically the "Main-Class" and "Class-Path" attributes.