# Maven to generate an image from an xm

Tags: image, maven, text, documentation-generation

Does anyone know a solution that generates an image (png or something else) from a text file (more precisely an XML) using Maven?

I frequently change some XML and would like to include it into the automatically generated documentation of a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a partial solution which is not perfect but does the job in such a way I can live with.
The solution consists of two elements:

1. I let Maven execute an external program using the exec-maven-plugin (hint taken from [How do I execute a program using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472376/how-do-i-execute-a-program-using-maven))
2. The external program is fed with the XML and generates a documentation including an image (originally I would like to have a pure image, however, I can live with the PDF). For this purpose, I use Oxygen (see https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/19.1/ug-editor/topics/documentation-XML-Schema-command-line.html)

For step 2, if anyone has a better solution, it would be welcome.