# Does a jar archive file created by `mvn package` neither contain its dependencies nor indicate which .class file contains main()?

Tags: java, maven

After running `mvn package` to package compiled java program containing `main()`,

- Is it correct that   the created jar file doesn't contain dependencies, so when running the jar file, I still have to provide dependencies?
- Is it correct that the created jar file doesn't indicate which .class file in it contains `main()` as the entry point, so when running the jar file, I still have to indicate the .class file which contains `main()`?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a side comment. Have you tried running a jar file packaged with that Maven command? As a pretty aged SO user you are probably aware of how the site and community works (ie https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users )

Comment: Sry, if previous comment might seem to be rude. If all of us would follow the answer from that meta question, there would be only a few new questions on SO in a day. But if would be good if you could avoid multiple questions in single post (and a little bit of pre-investigation also would be fine).

Answer (score 4):

It depends. By default, the answer is yes, it does not contain this information.

But Maven can be configured to contain these things. To also include the dependencies, one could use the [Maven Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) and bind it to the package phase with a `jar-with-dependencies` setting, or use the [Maven Shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) (also bound to the package phase). They are similar, although I prefer the Shade plugin as it supports so-called transformers that can work around some issues one gets when combining multiple jar files into one.

To have a main-class defined as entry point, you can  configure the Maven compile plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>my.main.Class</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If configured like that, you don't have to call `java -cp my.jar my.main.Class arguments`, but can just call it as `java -jar my.jar arguments`. If you still have additional dependencies, you would call it with `java -jar my.jar -cp dependencies/*.jar arguments`.

Comment: Thanks. When running a jar file, besides using command `java`,  can `mvn` be used? If yes, how? Do people often use `mvn` to run a jar file?

Comment: You can use `mvn exec`, e.g. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472376/how-do-i-execute-a-program-using-maven

Comment: I personally prefer to build a jar file and then run it, as it is independent of Maven which (for me) is just a development tool, but not a runtime tool I have on production servers. But I guess opinions vary on that topic.

Comment: Thanks.  (1) When using maven to package into a jar file, is the command always `mvn package`, in all the cases (whether indicating the .class file containing main(), and whether containing dependencies)?  The differences are only in the .pom files? (2)  When using maven to run a jar file, is the command always `mvn exec`? The differences are only in the .pom files?

Comment: (1) simply said, yes. (Maven is a beast with lots of plugins and options, there are exceptions where the answer is no, but that would be too much here), (2) I have not much experience with it, but I think yes. Typically, one configures everything in the `pom.xml`, and then a simpel `mvn <something>` does the job. If one needs to build different stuff, one could use so-called profiles in the pom, which can be enabled with `mvn <something> -Pprofile1` for example.